# Выравнивание ширины окна по дочернему

Tags: html, css

Имеется контейнер, в нем расположены элементы. если елемент не влазит в строку он переносится. Но проблема в том, что контейнер не уменьшается потом и равен максимальной ширине. (понятно станет, посмотрев на рисунок.)
Как сделать так, чтобы не было лишнего пространства(фиолетовый цвет), контейнер уменьшился?

```
.container{
    max-width: 700px
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item{}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поставить box-sizing:border-box

```
#example1 {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: С флексом я не знаком.

Comment: не получается этим способом